# Track changes of teams/players for different seasons

Tags: mysql, database-design

Consider the following tables: **Season, Club, Team** and **Player**

A team belongs to a club and has players, but each season the teams of a club and there players can change. I want to be able to follow all changes to the clubs/teams/players per season.

For the moment I create relationship tables like this:

**season_club** (season_id, club_id)
**season_team_player** (season_id, team_id, player_id)

A Team directly belongs to a club (has a foreign key column for this).

Is this the best way to go about this or is it better to create a new club for each season and store the season directly in **club**? I am trying like this because the club data doesn't change between season's and I want to track a club's changes of teams/players and also track the individual players their team changes.

I hope my question is somewhat clear...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the right sort of idea. You might find it simpler to accept a degree of redundancy in the form of a [season_club_team_player] table, but the alternative version - (season_club_id,season,club),(season_club_team_id,season_club_id,team_id),(season_club_team_id,player_id) - also works.

Comment: What happens if a player changes the club mid-season?

Comment: a player cannot change club mid-season

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the moment I create relationship tables like this:
>
> **season_club** (season_id, club_id)
>   **season_team_player** (season_id, team_id, player_id)
>
> A Team directly belongs to a club (has a foreign key column for this).

The second of these tables makes a lot of sense to me: together with your four main tables, this should provide all the information you require: you know which players played in which team in which season. And you can even see which teames had any players at all in a given season, from that conclude which teams existed in that season, and from the key on the club conclude which clubs where active in that season. So I don't see any need for the first table, unless your second table is incomplete, i.e. there were clubs for which you don't have data on existing teams, or for which you don't know the individual players.

In terms of performance, more redundancy might be desirable, but in terms of elegance, the above scheme, together with a bunch of nice views, should serve your needs just well.

> Is this the best way to go about this or is it better to create a new club for each season and store the season directly in **club**?

I'd suggest not to do this unless you want to track changes to the **club** data itself, e.g. a change in address or whatever. If you can identify the same club in different seasons without having to compare names of clubs, I'd consider this a great advantage.